# Entity framework - How to share some tables between multiple applications

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

We are trying to figure out a way to share tables between internal applications so we can have a single set of data for common things like Users and Departments.

If we have simple models like:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public virtual IQueryable<Department> Departments { get; set; }
}

public class Department
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual IQueryable<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

Right now we've been duplicating users (and departments, and the user->department maps) for each application they use, and that is becoming a maintenance nightmare.

How can we share a few tables between multiple applications that otherwise have completely different models and data?

Would using a slave table (still duplicated space wise) for these models with a master table that when updated updates all the slave tables?

We've looked at using the Multi-Tenant features in EF 6, but that just seems to create new User tables instead of being able to share a single user table between the different applications. Is there a way to use shared tables?

Edit:

We need to be able to reference the Users / Departments by their foreign keys, and hopefully have something like this for two different applications:

```
public class AppBHuzzah
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}

public class AppAFoo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Have you thought about separating them out into their on context so it can be in their own project and just referenced in all your applications or add another layer with web services that are consumed by all the other applications?

Comment: You could create views in each database that contain selects from the database where the user/department table lives. Then just add those models to your context.

Comment: A relatively easy way is to create an OData service for internal use. This keeps you loosely coupled from the master database, other than direct database links.

Answer (score 3):

Attempting to share database objects between applications, especially when the objects being shared contain critical data could lead to more chaos and headache.  So, it may be useful to attack this problem in a slightly different but architecturally scalable way for long-term benefits.

You will benefit from having clarity on what is *Master data* and what is *Transactional data* for each of your applications.  Loosely speaking, *Master data* will encompass all the nouns within the enterprise.  This usually means people, places and things required to conduct business.  Usually, users and departments are part of *Master data*.  The easy way to identify master data is to look at the data from the point of view of multiple applications and then seeing whether the data should have the same semantics for all the applications.  *Transactional data* on the other hand will cover all transactions.  For external systems this could be orders, payments, invoices, etc.  For internal application this could be expense reports, time sheets, salary slips, etc.

Once you have this clarity, *Master data* can be managed using well-known techniques covered under a discipline commonly called *Master data maintenance (MDM)*.  Some of the things you would do when applying principles of *Master data maintenance* are:

1. Each type of master data must be managed (created, updated, deleted, audited and archived) by a single system only.  Multiple applications must not be allowed to manage master data as this could lead to data inconsistencies and erroneous processing.
2. Applications that need to access master data must do so by making API calls to the MDM application responsible for the required master data.  This ensures things such as transactional consistency, data dependencies, reusability, etc.

It is not necessary for enterprises to have a single MDM system.  Different types of master data can be managed by different MDM systems, as long as there is no overlap between them and their roles are clearly demarcated.  MDM systems may not be overly complicated either.  For example, in one of my previous roles I designed a data access framework using Oracle stored procedures on top of a vast database schema that many applications wanted to connect to. Many of these applications were very old and could only invoke database code directly, which is why the solution was designed using stored procedures.  We had a large DBA pool that implemented the solution within 3 weeks.  Afterwards, we put Mule ESB on top of the stored procedures to provide a more modern API (XML, JSON, BSON, SOAP) to applications written on Java and .NET platforms.  Each consumer application got its own view of the system using a technology best matching their environment.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft suggests that SQL Server 2012 provides [Master Data Services](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/solutions-technologies/enterprise-information-management/master-data-services.aspx) which is what you actually need. [This MSDN post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb410798) could probably give you better insights on the issue.

Another approach would be to use a different database to save the Master data of persons and departments. Then, you could use a [Linked Server](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279.aspx) to create a "unified view" of the two databases. I suppose entity framework would have no problem to see the "unified view" of the two databases.

Hope I helped!